# syntax error near unexpected token `

Tags: command-line, bash

I am facing a problem when trying to **echo** all the child directory of the present directory.

Now my code is like this:

```
for d in */;
do
    echo "$d";
done
```

I tried with this as well:

```
for d in */;
do
    echo $d;
done
```

But every time I am getting the same error. This is:

```
'/test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `
'/test.sh: line 1: `for d in */;
```

How to solve this? Definitely I am doing some mistake. But can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The error message says there is a `\`` character at the beginning of the line, i.e., that the first line of the loop is `\`for d in */;` rather than `for d in */;`. I recommend that you **[edit]** your question to clarify whether or not the shell is correct in saying that you have a `\`` character.

Comment: I have not that ` character .. I have seen it using cat, using vi, using vim. Not found any ` in my shell code. @EliahKagan That's why I posted, what actually this is?

Comment: try ```set -x; ./test.sh``` see if you get some more output

Comment: You can try this although I'm pretty sure it'd be easier with \`ls ../\` https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

Comment: You will get a similar error if the file was saved with Windows `CRLF` line endings - please check with `file test.sh` or by running `cat -A` on the file and looking for `^M`

Comment: It could be a coding problem. Please take a look at the file by using a hex viewer like `od`. You may just delete and rewrite the line (and the line before, if there is one). If your editor has a shortcut for line deletion, prefer this (like Ctrl+K in nano and Geany).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command itself works fine:

```
$ for d in */; do echo "$d" ; done
subdir-A/
subdir-B/
```

However you have a hidden `'` in front of the `for` command. Perhaps the file was copied from Windows. The easiest solution is to create a new `test.sh` file and copy the above command into it.